# Do all axios calls before returning JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, axios

I am making an API server and in it, I need to call a convert method found on another API server for negative values.  I believe I have the code correct, but because of ASYNC I believe it is returning the value before doing all the conversions.  Here is the code:

```
                     for(let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
                        if (parseInt(results[i]['ACCOUNT_ID']) < 0) {
                          let account = axios.get('http://localhost:54545/api?request=convert&id='+results[i]['ACCOUNT_ID'])
                            .then(function (response) {
                              results[i]['ACCOUNT_ID'] = response.data.stringId;console.log(response.data.stringId);
                            })
                            .catch(function (error) {
                              console.log(error);
                            });
                        }
                      }

                      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                      return res.status(200).json(results);
```

I figure I need to use Promise.all somehow, but I'm not sure how to use it.
Any help would be appreciated and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```js
let arrayOfPromises = [];
for(let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
    if (parseInt(results[i]['ACCOUNT_ID']) < 0) {
        arrayOfPromises.push(axios.get('http://localhost:54545/api?request=convert&id='+results[i]['ACCOUNT_ID']));
     }
    }
    Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then( (responses) =>  {
            ///do stuff here
        })
        .then( () => {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    
    
    return res.status(200).json(results);
```

```
So you are going to be pushing all of the axios async calls into an
array

Then Promise.all all of those async calls

.then of of that

You will then have an array of all of the axios calls, so you can do
whatever logic you are trying to do

then set the headers 

finally return
```

You could also use the Bluebird .spread operator http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/spread.html
if you know the order of what is coming in.

You can also use the spread operator in ES6 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `axios.all` method to resolve all the promise. Here is the example taken from the axios documentations and here is the link https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios

```
function getUserAccount() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345');
}

function getUserPermissions() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345/permissions');
}

axios.all([getUserAccount(), getUserPermissions()])
  .then(axios.spread(function (acct, perms) {
    // Both requests are now complete
}));
```